# How to add post editor in sub menu page in wordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to make submenu page in wordpress where user can add content in same way like title and below that editor basically i need editor in my sidebar to add and delete its content.**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these two lines where you want the editor.

```
    $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor'; // Your id for the editor.
    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );
```

Codex reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor